# GeoServer responding with "No such feature type:" on REST PUT request

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I have a layer in GeoServer that is pulling data from a PostGIS Store. REST is set-up and worked with GET and PUT commands on a layer using a PostGIS Store with line data, but when a layer is using a different PostGIS Store with point data, GET works as a command but PUT does not. Using PUT, the API call returns "No such feature type" and a 404 Not Found response code.

If I change it to POST, I get a 405 Method Not Authorized error and the returned headers tell me that the Allowed methods are GET, PUT, DELETE. I'm using PostMan to test the GET and PUT REST API calls.

I'm unsure what is causing the PUT command to not recognize the layer when it's recognized with GET. I've tried making a new Layer from the Store, matching the name of the Layer to the NativeName, and looked around the settings and security for anything that would affect specific layers or API methods and it consistently says "No such feature type" when doing PUT calls to the layers using this PostGIS store with point data.

How do I get this REST PUT call to recognize the feature type when it recognizes it for GET?

The HTTP request:

```
PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/Surdex/featuretypes/aircraftlocations.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
Content-Length: 5194

<featureType>
    <name>aircraftlocations</name>
    <nativeName>aircraftpositions</nativeName>
    <namespace>
        <name>Surdex</name>
        <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="https://xxx.com/geoserver/rest/namespaces/Surdex.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </namespace>
    <title>aircraftlocations</title>
    <keywords>
        <string>features</string>
        <string>aircraftpositions</string>
        <string>aircraftlocations</string>
    </keywords>
    <nativeCRS>GEOGCS[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 
  DATUM[&quot;World Geodetic System 1984&quot;, 
    SPHEROID[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;7030&quot;]], 
    AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;6326&quot;]], 
  PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;, 0.0, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;8901&quot;]], 
  UNIT[&quot;degree&quot;, 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS[&quot;Geodetic longitude&quot;, EAST], 
  AXIS[&quot;Geodetic latitude&quot;, NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;4326&quot;]]</nativeCRS>
    <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
    <nativeBoundingBox>
        <minx>-180.0</minx>
        <maxx>180.0</maxx>
        <miny>-90.0</miny>
        <maxy>90.0</maxy>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </nativeBoundingBox>
    <latLonBoundingBox>
        <minx>-180.0</minx>
        <maxx>180.0</maxx>
        <miny>-90.0</miny>
        <maxy>90.0</maxy>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </latLonBoundingBox>
    <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <metadata>
        <entry key="cachingEnabled">false</entry>
    </metadata>
    <store class="dataStore">
        <name>Surdex:psql-2021_surdex_flight</name>
        <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="https://xxx.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Surdex/datastores/psql-2021_surdex_flight.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </store>
    <serviceConfiguration>false</serviceConfiguration>
    <simpleConversionEnabled>false</simpleConversionEnabled>
    <internationalTitle/>
    <internationalAbstract/>
    <cqlFilter>strtailnumber IN (&apos;N440EH&apos;, &apos;N441EH&apos;, &apos;N223SC&apos;, &apos;N27EH&apos;, &apos;N441FS&apos;,&apos;N7268P&apos;,&apos;N2NQ&apos;,&apos;N414EH&apos;,&apos;N72582&apos;, &apos;N72695&apos;,&apos;N262AS&apos;, &apos;N51CX&apos;, &apos;N63CX&apos;, &apos;N78MW&apos;, &apos;N8225Q&apos;,&apos;N35834&apos;,&apos;N350GB&apos;,&apos;N4948A&apos;,&apos;N528NR&apos;,&apos;N6479Y&apos;,&apos;N811HJ&apos;,&apos;N7139C&apos;,&apos;N528NP&apos;)</cqlFilter>
    <maxFeatures>0</maxFeatures>
    <numDecimals>0</numDecimals>
    <padWithZeros>false</padWithZeros>
    <forcedDecimal>false</forcedDecimal>
    <overridingServiceSRS>false</overridingServiceSRS>
    <skipNumberMatched>false</skipNumberMatched>
    <circularArcPresent>false</circularArcPresent>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <name>strtailnumber</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.String</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>dtend</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.sql.Timestamp</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>intheading</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.Short</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>intaltitude</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.Integer</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>intspeed</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.Integer</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>owner</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.String</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>track_label</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.String</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>owner_id</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.Short</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>st_endpoint</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point</binding>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</featureType>
```

And the error message from GeoServer log file

```
2023-02-06 13:30:51,883 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such feature type: Surdex,aircraftlocations
org.geoserver.rest.ResourceNotFoundException 404 NOT_FOUND: No such feature type: Surdex,aircraftlocations
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.FeatureTypeController.checkFeatureTypeExists(FeatureTypeController.java:430)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.FeatureTypeController.featureTypePut(FeatureTypeController.java:353)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor563.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: There is no WFS PUT - you are using the REST API to add data. Please edit your question to show us the data as **text** not pictures and clarify what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I've edited the question from WFS to REST, and removed the photos since they were demonstrating what I was saying in the text.

What I'm exactly trying to do is make a REST PUT request so that it recognizes the feature type that it can already recognize for GET requests.

Comment: We need to see the requests you are making and the error from the log file

Comment: Edited the question to include the HTTP request & error from the log file.